GTZAN Music Genre Classification: Tensor Mismatch and .wav file unrecognized
I'm using the GTZAN dataset and am trying to make a CNN music genre classifier. My .wav files are stores in a subdirectory called 'genres_original', which is within the root directory, 'Data'. I'm having two issues: my .wav files aren't being recognized although I'm certain they are in the right format for PyTorch (.wav) and I have a tensor mismatch issue which I think is related to the wav file problem as well?
import os
import glob
import random
import torch
import torchaudio
import pandas as pd
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Path to the directory containing .wav files
data_dir = 'Data/genres_original'

# List all .wav files
wav_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(data_dir, '*.wav'))
# print(wav_files)

# Extract labels and file paths
data = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.wav'):
            wav_file = os.path.join(root, file)
            genre, _ = os.path.splitext(file)
            genre = genre.split('.')[0]
            data.append((file, genre))

print(data)

# Convert to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['file_path', 'label'])

# Mapping of labels to indices
label_to_index = {label: idx for idx, label in enumerate(sorted(df['label'].unique()))}
index_to_label = {idx: label for label, idx in label_to_index.items()}

# Convert labels to indices
df['label'] = df['label'].map(label_to_index)

# print("Genre to int mapping:")
# print(label_to_index)

class AudioUtil():
    @staticmethod
    def open(audio_file):
        sig, sr = torchaudio.load(str(audio_file))
        return (sig, sr)

    @staticmethod
    def rechannel(aud, new_channel):
        sig, sr = aud
        if sig.shape[0] == new_channel:
            return aud
        if new_channel == 1:
            sig = sig.mean(dim=0, keepdim=True)
        else:
            sig = sig.expand(new_channel, -1)
        return (sig, sr)

    @staticmethod
    def resample(aud, new_sr):
        sig, sr = aud
        if sr == new_sr:
            return aud
        num_channels = sig.shape[0]
        resig = torchaudio.transforms.Resample(sr, new_sr)(sig[:1, :])
        if num_channels > 1:
            retwo = torchaudio.transforms.Resample(sr, new_sr)(sig[1:, :])
            resig = torch.cat([resig, retwo])
        return (resig, new_sr)

    @staticmethod
    def pad_trunc(aud, max_ms):
        sig, sr = aud
        num_rows, sig_len = sig.shape
        max_len = sr // 1000 * max_ms
        if sig_len > max_len:
            sig = sig[:, :max_len]
        elif sig_len < max_len:
            pad_begin_len = random.randint(0, max_len - sig_len)
            pad_end_len = max_len - sig_len - pad_begin_len
            pad_begin = torch.zeros((num_rows, pad_begin_len))
            pad_end = torch.zeros((num_rows, pad_end_len))
            sig = torch.cat((pad_begin, sig, pad_end), 1)
        return (sig, sr)

    @staticmethod
    def spectro_gram(aud, n_mels=64, n_fft=1024, hop_len=None):
        sig, sr = aud
        top_db = 80
        sgram = torchaudio.transforms.MelSpectrogram(
            sr, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_len, n_mels=n_mels)(sig)
        sgram = torchaudio.transforms.AmplitudeToDB(top_db=top_db)(sgram)
        return sgram

class GenreDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df, duration=5000, sr=22050, transform=None):
        self.df = df
        self.duration = duration
        self.sr = sr
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        file_path = self.df.iloc[idx, 0]
        label = self.df.iloc[idx, 1]
        # Convert the label to an integer if it's a string
        if isinstance(label, str):
            label = genre_to_int[label]
            # Split the file path to get the file name and extension separately
        file_dir, file_name = os.path.split(file_path)
        file_name_parts = file_name.split('.')
        # Assume the last part is the extension
        file_ext = file_name_parts[-1]
        # Reconstruct the file path with the correct extension
        corrected_file_path = os.path.join(file_dir, '.'.join(file_name_parts[:-1]) + '.' + file_ext)
        try:
            aud = AudioUtil.open(corrected_file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error opening file {corrected_file_path}: {e}")
            return None, None
        if aud is None:
            return None, None
        aud = AudioUtil.resample(aud, self.sr)
        aud = AudioUtil.rechannel(aud, 1)
        aud = AudioUtil.pad_trunc(aud, self.duration)
        sgram = AudioUtil.spectro_gram(aud, n_mels=64, n_fft=1024, hop_len=None)
        if self.transform:
            sgram = self.transform(sgram)
        return sgram, torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long)

# Ensure reproducibility
random.seed(42)
df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42).reset_index(drop=True)

# Split into train and validation sets (80% train, 20% validation)
train_df, val_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, stratify=df['label'], random_state=42)

train_dataset = GenreDataset(train_df)
val_dataset = GenreDataset(val_df)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=32, drop_last=True)

class AudioClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AudioClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 8, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(8, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 4 * 4, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv4(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 4 * 4)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = AudioClassifier().to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

def train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=20):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        model.train()
        running_loss = 0.0
        for inputs, labels in train_loader:
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(inputs)
            if outputs.size(0) != labels.size(0):
                print(f"Mismatch in batch sizes: outputs={outputs.size(0)}, labels={labels.size(0)}")
                print(f"Outputs shape: {outputs.shape}")
                print(f"Labels shape: {labels.shape}")
                continue
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
        
        epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}/{num_epochs - 1}, Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}')
        
        model.eval()
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for inputs, labels in val_loader:
                inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
                outputs = model(inputs)
                _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                correct += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
                total += labels.size(0)
        val_acc = correct.double() / total
        print(f'Validation Accuracy: {val_acc:.4f}')

train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=20)

When I print the file names, I get
Data/genres_original/blues_00067.wav 

and so on instead of just
blues_00067.wav,

which I think is stopping torchaudio from recognizing the format although they are .wav files. I tried the following to solve this:
# Extract labels and file paths
data = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.wav'):
            wav_file = os.path.join(root, file)
            genre, _ = os.path.splitext(file)
            genre = genre.split('.')[0]
            data.append((file, genre))

print(data)

This prints [(blues.00067.wav, blues),(country.00054.wav, country)....] which is what I am expecting.
That still did not solve the unrecognized file format issue. So I created the corrected_file_path var in getitem:
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        file_path = self.df.iloc[idx, 0]
        label = self.df.iloc[idx, 1]
        # Convert the label to an integer if it's a string
        if isinstance(label, str):
            label = genre_to_int[label]
            # Split the file path to get the file name and extension separately
        file_dir, file_name = os.path.split(file_path)
        file_name_parts = file_name.split('.')
        # Assume the last part is the extension
        file_ext = file_name_parts[-1]
        # Reconstruct the file path with the correct extension
        corrected_file_path = os.path.join(file_dir, '.'.join(file_name_parts[:-1]) + '.' + file_ext)
        try:
            aud = AudioUtil.open(corrected_file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error opening file {corrected_file_path}: {e}")
            return None, None
        if aud is None:
            return None, None
        aud = AudioUtil.resample(aud, self.sr)
        aud = AudioUtil.rechannel(aud, 1)
        aud = AudioUtil.pad_trunc(aud, self.duration)
        sgram = AudioUtil.spectro_gram(aud, n_mels=64, n_fft=1024, hop_len=None)
        if self.transform:
            sgram = self.transform(sgram)
        return sgram, torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long)

But that did not fix it either. I reinstalled soundfile too. Here is the exact error:
Error opening file disco.00069.wav: Error opening 'disco.00069.wav': System error.
Error opening file country.00053.wav: Error opening 'country.00053.wav': System error.
Error opening file reggae.00050.wav: Error opening 'reggae.00050.wav': System error.
Error opening file reggae.00095.wav: Error opening 'reggae.00095.wav': System error.
Error opening file metal.00057.wav: Error opening 'metal.00057.wav': System error.
(and so on for every file)

This leads to another error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HIDDEN_PATH/music.py", line 212, in <module>
    train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=20)
  File "HIDDEN_PATH/music.py", line 182, in train_model
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
  File "/HIDDEN_PATH/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 631, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "HIDDEN_PATH/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 675, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "HIDDEN_PATH/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 54, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/HIDDEN_PATH/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 316, in default_collate
    return collate(batch, collate_fn_map=default_collate_fn_map)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "HIDDEN_PATH/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 173, in collate
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/HIDDEN_PATH/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 173, in <listcomp>
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "HIDDEN_PATH/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 191, in collate
    raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem_type))
TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>

